# I can't get StringTemplate to indent

Tags: indentation, antlr3, stringtemplate

I have the following StringTemplate group

```
group RPInstr;

before(firstStat) ::= <<
<{<[beforeEnteringInstr(),firstStat]; anchor, separator="\n">}; anchor>
>>

beforeEnteringInstr() ::= "before();"
```

I am trying to make the first statement of a method to align with the instrumentation code ("before();").
However, what I am getting right now is something like this:

```
public  int method() {
  before();
System.out.println("testing");
  System.out.println("testing again");
}
```

What is the proper way to indent before(); and the next statement so I get the following?

```
public  int method() {
  before();
  System.out.println("testing");
  System.out.println("testing again");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: the options that I am using in my grammar are the following

options {output=template; rewrite=true; backtrack=true; memoize=true;}

Comment: Asked here as well: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/qkwv4siqggrht2pa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the expr in before(firstStat) is not indented.  No reason for ST to indent then.